# What is a resting limit order?

Tags: limit-order-book

What exactly is a **resting limit order**?  I could not find a definition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aSearch?search=resting%20limit%20order) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=resting%20limit%20order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An un-marketable limit order (buy limit price is < lowest offer, sell limit price is > highest bid) that has a time in force allowing it to be placed onto a matching engine's limit order book. It is said to "rest" on the book. If the time in force is Immediate or Cancel and the order is unmarketable, it is canceled back to the participant unfilled.